# How to clip a container with another in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, clip

I am having trouble finding the best way to do this:

The idea is that the red part is visible, and the green part is transparent, so i can see the image clearly in the center, and with a bit of opacity in the edges

[image]

My idea is to either Clip a Container with another one (Don't know how to do it)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      Image.asset(
        'assets/images/test.jpeg',
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
             bottom: BorderSide(
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.4),
             ),
             top: BorderSide(
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.4),
             ),
             left: BorderSide(
                width: 40,
                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.4),
             ),
             right: BorderSide(
                width: 10,
                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.4),
            ),
          ),
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),

)
```

also you can do this by only use container:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      border: Border(
        bottom: BorderSide(
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.4),
        ),
        top: BorderSide(
          width: 100,
          color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.4),
        ),
        left: BorderSide(
          width: 40,
          color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.4),
        ),
        right: BorderSide(
          width: 10,
          color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.4),
        ),
      ),
      image: DecorationImage(
        image: AssetImage('assets/images/test.jpeg'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      color: Colors.transparent,
    ),
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks, but what i want is to be able to have the below image visible, with the color only on those borders

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out. @cgutierr

Comment: Hi, I guess I'm explaining myself really bad
What i want is:
My image with a border semi transparent (Yellow, red, i dont mind the color) and in the center a clean image
Going to quickly sketch it in photoshop
(Updated the question, see image on top)

Comment: Thanks, i tried this before and worked, problem with this is that i cant set custom heights for the border example:
top border taking 20 pixels, left and right 10 and bottom 200 bixels, for example

Comment: yes you can, I updated my answer.

Comment: Yep u right, what can't be done is setting a borderradius (if u remember my first photo had the radius) that's where the problems come, i added this to your code: [borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),], then it breaks, u'll get [
The following is not uniform:
BorderSide.width
The relevant error-causing widget was
Container]

that's why i thought of clipping with containers